# how to detect microphone permission pop up

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter, avaudiorecorder, nsnotifications

I have an animating sine wave in my app that needs to be reset when the user hits the home button or locks their phone (turning off the screen).  Once the user brings the app back to the foreground, the sine wave animation is triggered again.  This works fine until I realized it was occurring when the microphone access permission pops up.  So the microphone access pops up, causing my app to go into the background and the animation to turn off, but the app is still visible.  Any way I can know that the mic access pop up is occurring, so I can make some kind of `if` statement?

```
-(void) appDidEnterForeground:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if( viewIsUp == NO)
    {
         [self.sineWave.layer removeAllAnimations];
    }
     else
    {
         [self.sineWave animateWave];
    }
}


-(void) appDidEnterBackground:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if(viewIsUp)
    {
        [self.sineWave.layer removeAllAnimations];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally set `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` as the notification to call `appDidEnterBackground`.  When the microphone access pop up would display, the only notification that would get called was `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification`.  So when the home button was tapped or the screen was locked, I would remove the animation when `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` was called and when the mic access pop up displayed, I would leave the animation as it is  when `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` gets called.  Worked out nicely.  Hope this helps someone.